# OperationalError:Connection to server at "IP_HERE", port 5432 failed:Connection timed out Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP conc

Tags: python, database, azure, azure-functions, psycopg2

I have a python script, which I deployed on Azure Functions (HTTP Request). My python script contains a connection string to connect with DB using psycopg2, Everything is working fine in my machine. But when I deployed it on Azure Functions it is showing ** OperationalError: connection to server at "20.231.229.175", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py**

I tried few different libraries to connect with postgresql DB, But still getting same error.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- As far I know this is a firewall issue when I deployed a python function and tried to connect to the `postgresqldb` it gave me the following error
  [image]
  Similar to yours.
- Now I whitelisted Ip from the azure functions. These Ip address are of azure function they will be available under the `networking` tab just white list these Ip address in you postgresql server
  [image]
- Now I ran the function again which creates a table and add rows I got the following result

[image]

Comment: Yeah I did the same, but in my case after every time I press Test/Run I am getting different IP assigned, Which I need to add in whitelist too, But every time I press Test/Run button I am getting new IP. How to deal with that?